# Return CheckBoxes.LinkedCell address VBA

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I use the following code to automatically generate a new checkbox and link a cell to it:

```
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add().LinkedCell = Selection.Address
```

I want to create another `sub` which should change the background color of the `.LinkedCell` cell of the checkbox when the checkbox is checked (blue) or unchecked (red). I will have about 200 checkboxes in the worksheet.

Is there a way to get/return the `.LinkedCell` address of the currently checked/unchecked checkbox so that the `sub` can change the background color of that cell?

For example let's presume that the `.LinkedCell` is the cell in which the checkbox was initially placed. This would be the initial status of each checkbox:

[image]

and this would be the result after the user checks/unchecks the checboxes:

[image]

until now I used this code to change the background color of the checkbox itself. But I don't want that, I want to change the color of the `.LinkedCell`.

```
Sub SetMacro()
    Dim cb
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If cb.OnAction = "" Then cb.OnAction = "CheckedUnchecked"
    Next cb
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub CheckedUnchecked()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).DrawingObject
        If .Value = 1 Then
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        Else
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "currently checked/unchecked checkbox"?  Are you looking for an event?

Comment: (a) Could you just conditionally format the cell based on whether it is `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: (b) Do you have code linked to the CheckBox's Click event?  If so, you should be able to just use the CheckBox's .LinkedCell property, and then set that cell's background colour to whatever you like.

Comment: @YowE3K thank you for the very intelligent point (a) :)
I detailed the explanation.
Nonetheless I would like to do it with some kind of a click event... not sure how it works but would like to learn and understand

Comment: Re (a) - you could use CF to set it to blue if `=TRUE` and to red if `=AND(cell<>"",cell=FALSE)`

Comment: Re (b) - I have posted an answer showing a revised `CheckedUnchecked` subroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace your CheckedUnchecked code with the following:

```
Sub CheckedUnchecked()
    With ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).LinkedCell)
        If .Value Then
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        Else
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```